# Why do these pointers cause a crash?

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm a bit confused as to why the following code crashes:

```
int main(){
    int *a;
    int *b;

    *a = -2;
    *b = 5;  //This line causes a crash on my system.

    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't memory automatically be allocated for two pointers and two integers before run-time because of the declarations?

Or must you always explicitly allocate memory?

Comment: "Shouldn't memory automatically be allocated " -- Where did you get such an idea? It's certainly false. How much memory should be allocated to a *pointer* that can point to an arbitrarily long array of `int`?

Comment: @Code-Guru: I would have emphasized the *before* rather than the _must_. ;-)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Good point(er)

Comment: On most systems the first line will crash too ... and odds are it did on yours.

Comment: Don't shoot in the dark. Get a book on C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You've only declared the pointers, not what they point to.  The pointers are allocated on the stack, and since you've not initialized them to anything, their values are garbage.

```
int main() {
    int a = 7;
    int *p_a;    // p_a contains whatever garbage was on the stack at its
                 // location when main() is called. (Effectively points nowhere).

    p_a = &a;    // p_a points to (gets the address of) variable a, also on
                 // the stack.

    printf("Before: a = %d\n", a);   // prints 7

    *p_a = -2;      

    printf("After: a = %d\n", a);    // prints -2

    return 0;
}
```

I would code up the above example, and step through it in a debugger. You'll see what I mean about what `p_a` is pointing to.

---

> Shouldn't memory automatically be allocated for two pointers and two integers before run-time because of the declarations?

I only see you specifying two pointers. Where are the two integers?

> Or must you always explicitly allocate memory?

Pointers have to point to *something*. Either local variables on the stack, or `malloc`'d memory from the heap.

Comment: Doesn't int * a declare a pointer that will point to an integer?

Comment: @Josh Consider the phrase "her dog". This is a reference to someone's' dog, but it won't do to tell me "give her dog a bone" if you haven't told me who she is. Similarly, "pointer to an int" doesn't tell the system which int it is.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
int* a;
*a = -2;
```

`a` is an uninitialized pointer, dereferencing of which produces ***undefined behavior***, that you were luckily able to observe as a crash of your application.

You need to initialize the pointer (make it point to the valid memory) before you dereference it (i.e. before you use `*`, *the dereference operator*):

```
int a;
int* pA = &a;
*pA = -2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
int m;
int n;
m = n;
```

This is invalid because you're trying to use `n` but you haven't assigned a value to it. Now:

```
int *a;
*a = -2;
```

Likewise, this is invalid because you're trying to use `a` but you haven't assigned a value to it. The value of `a` is not an `int`, it's a pointer to `int`. For example,

```
int someint;
a = &someint;
*a = -2;
```

puts -2 into `someint`. Without the assignment to `a`, the place to put -2 is undeterminable. Also,

```
a = malloc(sizeof(int));
*a = -2;
```

Here, `a` is given the value of the address of some location in the heap; -2 goes into that heap location.

Perhaps an analogy would be helpful:

Consider the phrase "her dog". This is a reference to someone's' dog, but it won't do to tell me "give her dog a bone" if you haven't told me who she is. Similarly, "pointer to an int" doesn't tell the system which int it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have just declared pointers but you haven't initialized them. So, you can't be sure that `*b = 5` is causing the program to crash. It could be `*a = -2` as well. To fix it, you should initialize your pointers as well.

```
int aval = -2;
int bval = 5;

int *a = &aval; // declared and initialized pointers
int *b = &bval; 

// Now you can change the value using the pointer
*a = 15;
*b = 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *a and *b pointers are not initializated properly.
Try this one:

```
int my_a;
int my_b;

int *a;
int *b;

a = &my_a;  // init the pointer a to the direction of my_a int variable
b = &my_b;

*a = 3;  // set the my_a value via pointer
*b = 2;
```